# How to download a Jupyter Notebook from GitHub?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, ipython

This is a fairly basic question.

I am working on a data science project inside of a Pandas tutorial. I can access my Jupyter notebooks through my Anaconda installation. The only problem is that the tutorial notebooks (exercise files) are on GitHub.

My question: how do I download the exercise files from GitHub and then have them display in the Jupyter notebook section on my computer so that I can use them interactively?

I am very new to Jupyter Notebooks. So far, I have been using PyCharm to execute all of my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the tutorial is a GitHub repo, sure. Clone the repository. Run jupyter-notebook and open the notebook there.

Answer (score 16):

You can do:

1. Open the jupyter notebook you want to run.
2. Click on: `Raw`

   [image]
3. Save <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
4. Remove:  `.txt`

[image]

5. Now navigate to the directory where `notebook` is downloaded in jupyter notebook and open it.

Answer (score 4):

This is a tool that I came across to run Jupyter notebooks: [Binder](https://mybinder.org/).

You just need to input the repo you are looking at, the branch, and the path. Then you can interactively run the notebook.

The notebook gets hosted by the website, so you don't need to worry about computing power on your machine or installing all the required packages.

Answer (score 1):

1. First click on Raw
2. Then, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
3. IMPORTANT STEP: Ii ipynb extension is already present after the filename. Clear the extension and rewrite it and save it
4. Go to location where you saved .ipynb file
5. Open the jupyter file

Hope it works